# How to convert messages between CoAP and MQTT protocols?

Tags: mqtt, networking, protocols, coap, interoperability

I am a master student and my topic is about making protocol conversion among IoT communication protocols for example between CoAP and MQTT in order to make the devices that use MQTT protocol to communicate with the devices that use CoAP protocol.

I'm not sure how to get devices to communicate using CoAP and MQTT; is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You would need a 'gateway' that can translate from CoAP to MQTT (and vice versa). Various examples exist, such as:

- [emq-coap](https://github.com/emqtt/emq-coap) which allows CoAP clients to communicate with an instance of the [EMQ](http://emqtt.io/) MQTT broker (a usage example is given in the [README](https://github.com/emqtt/emq-coap#client-usage-example))
- [Eclipse Ponte](https://www.eclipse.org/ponte/), which bridges HTTP, MQTT and CoAP. An example is given that you can send a message  to `mqtt://<your ponte>/<your thing>` and then access it via CoAP with `coap://<your ponte>/r/<your thing>`. [This blog post](http://mohanp.com/ponte-a-m2m-bridge-for-mqtt-coap-and-http/) has a brief example of using MQTT and HTTP if you want to see it illustrated in more detail.